# Browser database that can sync between other devices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, indexeddb, web-sql

I am developing a Web App and I would like to add functionality that enables users to use it while offline (Application Cache).

I am looking for a tool that can sync the browser's DB (IndexedDB) between offline devices and then sync with MySQL when internet access returns.

PouchDB has that kind of functionality. You have multiple PouchDBs for each device and you do a bidirectional replication (sync) between each PouchDB and the CouchDB. But I need MySQL support.